# Require field to implement multiple interfaces without using type argument

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm using type argument `T` in order to force `values` to be serializable collection of `String`.

```
class Foo<T>(val values: T) where T : Collection<String>, T : Serializable
```

Is it possible to achieve similar result without type argument?
Ideal solution would look like the following **pseudocode**:

```
class Foo(val values: Collection<String> & Serializable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to specify that there must be two interfaces an object implements, you could however do if checks in the runtime but the problem is that they are checks on runtime so at compile time they would look ok.

So to better approach this, you should create a third interface that implements both the interfaces, and accept the values which implements the third interface.

```kotlin
interface SerializableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, Serializable

class Foo(val values: SerializableCollection<String>)
```

Probably it is the only solution in here, see a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108182/using-parameter-that-implements-multiple-interfaces-pre-generics) in java.